# Firebase Realtime Database - Web / Javascript - how to to execute multiple write operations as a single batch

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed the Firebase Firestore give us the option to execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete().

Is it possible on Firebase Realtime as well?

---

Basically, I have the following data:

```
main: {
    first: {
        keywords: {
            one: { active: false, required: false },
            two: { active: false, required: false },
            three: { active: false, required: false },
        }
    }
}
```

I have created an action to update a single value like this:

```
database.ref(`main/${category}/keywords/${keyword}/`).update({ active })
```

I need to create a new action to update the active value of all keywords' children at once.

I know that I could update the "keywords" just by updating the whole object like this:

database.ref(`main/${category}/keywords`).update(UPDATED OBJECT HERE)

However, just out of curiosity is there a way where I could just loop into keywords and update specific values? Maybe something like this?

```
database.ref(`main/${category}/keywords/`).forEach(item => item.update({ active }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) would help you:

```
let dbConnection = firebase.database().ref(`main/${category}/keywords/`);
dbConnection.once('value', dataSnapshot => {
  dataSnapshot.forEach(child => {
    child.ref.update({ active });
  });
});
```